# Creating MapCameraPosition from CLLocationManager initialiser/self error when trying to tie them

Tags: swift, swiftui, mapkit, core-location

Trying to use new Swift @Observable to monitor GPS position within SwiftUI content view. But how do I tie the latest locations to the SwiftUI Map's mapCameraPosition?

Well ideally the answer could cover:

1. How to fix this error - So get map tracking along with the User Position, but also
2. How to include facility to turn on/off the map moving to track the user position (which I'll need to do next).  So could be tracking, then disable, move map around and have a look at things, then click button to start syncing the mapcameraposition to the GPS location again

Refer to error I'm embedded in the code below.

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

@Observable
final class NewLocationManager : NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    var location: CLLocation? = nil
    private let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    func startCurrentLocationUpdates() async throws {
        if locationManager.authorizationStatus == .notDetermined {
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        }
        for try await locationUpdate in CLLocationUpdate.liveUpdates() {
            guard let location = locationUpdate.location else { return }
            self.location = location
        }
    }
   
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var newlocationManager = NewLocationManager()
    
    @State private var cameraPosition: MapCameraPosition = .region(MKCoordinateRegion(
        center: newlocationManager.location?.coordinate ?? <#default value#>,
        span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.25, longitudeDelta: 0.25)
    ))
    // GET ERROR: Cannot use instance member 'newlocationManager' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Map(position: $cameraPosition)
            Text("New location manager: \(newlocationManager.location?.description ?? "NIL" )") // works
        }
        .task {
            try? await newlocationManager.startCurrentLocationUpdates()
        }
        
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says, you cannot make use of `newlocationManager`
before the initialization of the view is complete.

Try using `.onAppear{...}` as shown in the example code.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var newlocationManager = NewLocationManager() // <--- here
    
    @State private var cameraPosition: MapCameraPosition = .region(MKCoordinateRegion(
        center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 35.68, longitude: 139.75), // <--- here, adjust
        span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.25, longitudeDelta: 0.25)
    ))
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Map(position: $cameraPosition)
            Text("New location manager: \(newlocationManager.location?.description ?? "NIL" )") // works
        }
        .task {
            try? await newlocationManager.startCurrentLocationUpdates()
        }
        .onAppear { // <--- here
            cameraPosition = .region(MKCoordinateRegion(
                center: newlocationManager.location?.coordinate 
                ?? CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 35.68, longitude: 139.75),
                span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.25, longitudeDelta: 0.25)
            ))
        }
        
    }
}
```

EDIT-3:

```
@Observable
final class NewLocationManager: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    var location: CLLocation? = nil
    private let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    func startCurrentLocationUpdates() async throws {
        if locationManager.authorizationStatus == .notDetermined {
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        }
        for try await locationUpdate in CLLocationUpdate.liveUpdates() {
            guard let location = locationUpdate.location else { return }
            DispatchQueue.main.async { // <--- here
                self.location = location
            }
        }
    }
   
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var newlocationManager = NewLocationManager()
    
    @State var cameraPosition: MapCameraPosition = .automatic
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Map(position: $cameraPosition)
            Text("\(newlocationManager.location?.description ?? "NIL" )")
                .foregroundStyle(.red)
        }
        .task {
            try? await newlocationManager.startCurrentLocationUpdates()
        }
        // --- here
        .onReceive(newlocationManager.location.publisher) { location in
            cameraPosition = .region(MKCoordinateRegion(
                center: location.coordinate,
                span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.0025, longitudeDelta: 0.0025) // <--- here
            ))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this does not seem to work - the changes to location from newlocationManager (observed object), whilst are getting updated in Text subview, are NOT being used to update the cameraPosition... any ideas why

Comment: How about having a `var cameraPosition = MapCameraPosition()` in your `NewLocationManager`
 with the appropriate updates, and using that directly in the `Map(position: $newlocationManager.cameraPosition)`.

Comment: is it like you have to determine calculated state data updates outside the SwiftUI view, in an observed object, and SwiftUI View can then create the view based on all the worked out state data then?  No way in a SwiftUI View to programatically update some state data with other data changes?

Comment: Ok, looks like the different approach, with var cameraPosition in the NewLocationManager (EDIT-2 now deleted) 
 does not work either.
 The original answer with `.onAppear(..)` only updates the cameraPosition once.
 So added EDIT-3 answer with using `onReceive(...)`. Seems to work for me.