location manager implementation not grabbing location on app startup for MapKit MapView
Here are our implementations for the location manager and mapview. We get this specific error on app startup where our main view calls MapView() within it: 'Failed to find user's location: The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 1.)'
location manager:
class LocationManager: NSObject, ObservableObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    @Published var location: CLLocationCoordinate2D?
    private let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        locations.last.map {
            self.location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: $0.coordinate.latitude, longitude: $0.coordinate.longitude)
        }
    }
    
    func locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization(_ manager: CLLocationManager) {
            if locationManager.authorizationStatus == .authorizedWhenInUse ||
                locationManager.authorizationStatus == .authorizedAlways {
                locationManager.requestLocation()
            }
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
           print("Failed to find user's location: \(error.localizedDescription)")
       }

}

MapView:
struct MapView: View {
    @ObservedObject var locationManager = LocationManager()
    var body: some View {
        Map(initialPosition: .region(region))
            .onAppear {
                            // Update region based on locationManager's location
                            if let userLocation = locationManager.location {
                                self.region = MKCoordinateRegion(
                                    center: userLocation,
                                    span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.2, longitudeDelta: 0.2)
                                )
                            }
                        }
    }
    @State private var region: MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(
            center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 34.011_286, longitude: -116.166_868),
            span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.2, longitudeDelta: 0.2)
        )
}

#Preview {
    MapView()
}

We want the app to grab location of the user on app startup and have the map centered around them we have tried many implementations but unsure how to move forward or if we are going about implementing LocationManager wrong.

Note, you should be using @StateObject var locationManager = LocationManager()

this post/answer (EDIT-3) could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77754586/creating-mapcameraposition-from-cllocationmanager-initialiser-self-error-when-tr

Doesn’t CLError.Code of 1 mean that authorization status is denied? Have you checked the in the Settings app for you particular app and confirmed whether location services were actually authorized. It’s a good way to confirm whether location services have been granted. I don’t see anything in this code that handles the scenario when authorizationStatus was .denied. FWIW, once location services are denied, the only way to turn it back on is the Settings app…
